# Is it possible to create an Android database without external tools?

Tags: android, database, sdk, package

I have been searching for this for the past few days and every tutorial I see needs for me to use an external package. Is there anything built into the Android SDK that would allow me to create a database? I thought I saw something on it a long time ago, but I can't find anything to back that foggy memory up.

Comment: You can always write your own database infrastructure. :) It'd be a fun project.

Comment: Hmmmm. I'm intrigued. Is it easy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean creating SQLite database? The `SQLiteDatabase::openOrCreateDatabase()` will create sqlite database and it's part of the android SDK:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: Thank you. Just by Googling "SQLiteDatabase::openOrCreateDatabase()" I found a tutorial. Thanks :)